# Accessing adjacent remote network from existing network tunnel in pfsense ipsec

Tags: networking, ipsec, pfsense

We have two offices, A and B, with IP segment 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.20.0/24 respectively, connected to each other using IPsec tunnel mode.

Additionally, office B has an IPsec tunnel mode connection to the vendor network (10.0.1.1/32). The vendor network only allows incoming traffic from office B (192.168.20.0/24).

My question is, how can we reach the vendor network (10.0.1.1/32) from office A (192.168.10.0/24)? I've attempted to set up a NAT hybrid outbound to mask office A's network to appear as though it's coming from office B, but it hasn't worked.